# django routes help

Tags: django, url, routes

Hay guys, im making a simple car sale website. I have a nice little urlpattern which works well as expected

```
/car/1/
```

goes to a car with that id, simple?

However, for SEO reasons i want to add extra data to the URL, but ignore it.

```
/car/1/ford/focus
```

as an example, how would i go about modifying my patters to take the extra parts into consideration?

the 2 patterns would go to the same place and load up the same view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't help your SEO - in fact it will actively hurt it. If `/car/1/`, `/car/1/ford/`, `/car/1/ford/focus/` all go to the same URL, you have actually decreased your search equity for that page. This is a very bad idea.

If you really want to do it, it's very simple:

```
r'^car/(?P<car_id>\d+)/.*/$'
```

but I really wouldn't do this. A much better idea is to leave out the ID and use the make and model to get the car:

```
r'^car/(?P<make>\w+)/(?P<model>\w+)/$'
```

So now you have URLs in the form `/car/ford/focus/`, and in your view you can do:

```
def myview(request, make, model):
    car = Car.objects.get(make=make, model=model)
```

Comment: I agree, much better to leave out the id and create an accessible URL - see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/us-cranky8.html for more info

Comment: I get this error Caught an exception while rendering: Incorrect integer value: 'ford' for column 'make_id' at row 1

Comment: I don't know how you're storing make and model values on your Car model, so I just used charfields. If they're actually foreignkeys, you'll need to alter that `.get` accordingly - see the documentation for how to do lookups across relations. If you still can't work it out, posta new question and include your models code.

Answer (score 1):

Use SlugField (or AutoSlugField) for build SEO friendly URLs

Comment: I have actually moved onto this method